# Angular 2 - error in error

Tags: angular, webpack

why its showing below like in console.

am trying to do like [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/Uo1coU9i1GsB1I4U3809?p=preview)

```
ERROR in Error: Tried to find bootstrap code, but could not. Specify either statically analyzable bootstrap code or pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.
    at Object.resolveEntryModuleFromMain (D:\Users\cli-quickstart\cli-quickstart\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\entry_resolver.js:131:11)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then (D:\Users\cli-quickstart\cli-quickstart\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:238:54)                                                                                                                              at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

actually am copy and pasting that plunker example in already exist project.

thanks in advance

Comment: you need to provide [mcve] here

Comment: also am getting  `Error loading https://unpkg.com/rxjs/operators/refCount.js as "./refCount" from https://unpkg.com/rxjs/operators/share.js` in plunkr

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you made the app using Angular CLI, you should import bootstrap in your package.json. The package looks like this:

```
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7"
```

Then after the npm install you want to include it in the styles section of angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ]
```

Then it should see your bootstrap code.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states: **pass in an entryModule to the plugins options.** As in plunker you got to bootstrap your main module in main.ts as follows

```
//main entry point
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppModule} from './app.module';

setTimeout(() => 
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
, 2000);
```